# Replace onkeydown atribute html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a thing where you input text, press enter, runs functionOne, then when you press enter again it runs functionTwo.

```
<input type="text" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) myFunction()" id="theText" name="reverseMe" value=""><br>
```

That is my textbox

```
document.getElementsByName("theText")[0].onKeyDown = "if(event.keyCode==13) functionTwo()";
```

that is at the end of functionOne
The problem is that when I hit enter it still runs functionOne.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines. No need to store a global variable. Note the `data-call-count` field in the HTML and the `input.dataset.callCount` in the JavaScript.

```js
function myFunction(input) {
  var callCount = Number(input.dataset.callCount) + 1
  input.dataset.callCount = callCount
  if(callCount === 1) functionOne()
  else if(callCount === 2) functionTwo()
  else console.log('Call ', callCount)
}

function functionOne() {
  console.log("I'm function one!")
}

function functionTwo() {
  console.log("I'm function two!")
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) myFunction(this)" id="theText" name="reverseMe" value="" data-call-count="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store an attribute to your `textarea` to save the number of iterations, example:

```
function handleKeyDown (event) {
  var textarea = event.target;
  var iterations = textarea.getAttribute('data-iterations') || 0;
  if (+iterations <= 1) {
    callFunctionOne();
    textarea.setAttribute('data-iterations', +iterations + 1);
  } else {
    callFunctionTwo();
    textarea.setAttribute('data-iterations', 0);
  }
}

// Then add the event listener to your textarea
document.getElementsByName("theText")[0].addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
```

This way whenever you try to interact with your textarea, the code will first check if there was an iteration before. If it were, the code will call your second function and reset the iteration count. The next time you call it, the first function will be called again.

This is also useful because you can easily get the status of your checkbox from other functions by simply checking its `data-iterations` attribute.